# C# Form Application Try To Change Component Value Which Is Created At Running Time

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, modbus, tablelayoutpanel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihjc1.png)In my project,  i got a TableLayoutPanel list which is created according to SQL query.On this panel i got many labels and textboxes. And i create all of this component when the project start running.
I want to change some textbox values from another methods but i cant.
Can someone help me ? I'll share some screenshot .

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)

Comment: Is there any issue in calling those methods and setting returned values in textbox ?

Comment: A tablelayoutpanel has limited features.  I've given up trying to use it because it never does what I need.  I simply create my own array of panels by creating a main panel and then adding an array of child panels.

Comment: I created what i need while sqldatareader reading. But in another method i have to change the values which is own created i can share screenshots but stackoverflow doesnt allow :(